# Java Convert List<TypeA> to List<TypeB>

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist, converters

For example

```
class TypeA {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
}

class TypeB {
    private String a;
}
```

Now I have a list of `TypeA`, and I only need the information `a` from `TypeA`.
What's the most efficient way to convert `List<TypeA>` to `List<TypeB>`

Comment: I don't know that efficiency is a concern here. You're always going to need to iterate over every element in `List<TypeA>` and create new instances of `TypeB`. Are you running into some issue? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Efficient in what way - Runs fastest? Requires least amount of thinking? If "runs fastest" - why do you have TypeA and TypeB to begin with, the most efficient way could be getting rid of one and using only the other? Do you even need all items in the list?

Comment: Because there's no setters, getters or constructor, you... *can't* ...convert these types.  You have no way to get or put data from either object.

Comment: `List<TypeB> listOfBs = listOfAs.stream().map(a -> {TypeB b = new TypeB(); b.a = a.a; return b;}).collect(Collectors.toList()`

Comment: @Makoto Not strictly true.  If the conversion code was located in the same Java file as both those types, it could be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer depends on what you mean by "efficient".

```
// Option 1
List<TypeB> bList = new ArrayList<>();
for (TypeA a : aList) {
    bList = new TypeB(s.getA());
}

// Option 2
List<TypeB> bList = aList.stream()
        .map(TypeA::getA)
        .map(TypeB::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Option 3
List<TypeB> bList = aList.stream().map(a -> new TypeB(s.getA())).collect(toList());
```

The first *performs* best. That is one type of efficiency.

The second and third are single statements. That is another type of efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

Efficient in what way? In terms of **maintainability** and **clarity**, I vote for object mapping libraries such as [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) or [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) that are based on both the reflection and annotations. In case of MapStruct, you can define a mapping for the objects `TypeA` and `TypeB` and use the relevant method within the same mapping interface.

```
@Mapper
public interface TypeA Mapper {

    @Mapping(target="a")
    TypeB typeAToTypeB(TypeA typeA) 

    List<TypeB> listOfTypeAToListOfTypeB(List<TypeA> list);
}
```

You can always use just a simple iteration using [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) or a simple for-loop:

```
List<TypeB> listOfTypeB = listOfTypeA.stream()
    .map(typeA -> new TypeB(typeA.getA())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) method is well suited for this type of data transformation.

```java
List<TypeB> bList = aList.stream().map(typeA -> new TypeB(typeA.a)).toList();
```